# sed - replacing string with variable containing?

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

Please help, I am not getting anywhere despite extensive search in here.

I have a html file, and I want to replace some of the links it it - problem is, some of the links have a ? in it.

```
original='http://old.com/img_7251.jpg?w=300&#038;h=200'
replace='http://new.com/img_7251.jpg'
sed -i "s#$original#$replace#g" inputfile.html
```

it works when there is no ? in the original string, with ? it doesn't do anything.
I do have a logic behind, so I will need to replace it with variables.

May escaping a ? in the original variable will help? but how?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use ~ instead of # and add ~g for global at the end of sed, Please use this:

```
sed -i "s~$original~$replace~g" inputfile.html
```

Comment: damn ... (btw. I just forgot the #g at the end, so that was not it), but I switched the # to ~ and it worked. I am totally puzzled, for years I am working now under the assumption, that it does not matter what character you are using for SED (the typical example is /, I always use # when there is a slash in it). I will need to read up on this.

Comment: Your $original variable contained a # character.

Comment: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️